# Piping values to New-Item to create directories in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I've got a directory, `C:\temp\test\`, containing three DLL's I've called First.dll, Second.dll, Third.dll.  I want to create sub-directories named after each of the DLL's.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$dirName = "Tenth"
new-item $dirName -ItemType directory
```

That works.  It created a sub-directory called "Tenth".

This also works:

```
(get-childitem -file).BaseName | select $_
```

It returns:

```
First
Second
Third
```

I've checked the type of the output from that command and it tells me "select $_" is of type System.String.

Now the bit that doesn't work:

```
(get-childitem -file).BaseName | new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory
```

I get the following error repeated three times:

```
new-item : An item with the specified name C:\temp\test already exists.
At line:1 char:34
+ (get-childitem -file).BaseName | new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\temp\test:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

The current folder I'm executing the commands from is `C:\temp\test\` .

I haven't been able to find any similar examples on the Internet to show me where I'm going wrong.  Can anyone give me any pointers?  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_` references each item as it comes along the pipeline so you will need to pipe to `ForEach-Object` for your line to work, like this:

```
(get-childitem -file).BaseName | ForEach-Object {new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory}
```

This will create the item in the current powershell directory, you can also specify `-Path` if you want to create the folders somewhere else.

```
(get-childitem -file).BaseName | ForEach-Object {new-item -Name $_ -Path C:\MyFolder -ItemType directory}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Now the bit that doesn't work:
>
> `(get-childitem -file).BaseName | new-item -Name $_ -ItemType directory`

This way, it works and doesn't need the `ForEach-Object`:

`(dir -file).BaseName|ni -name{$_} -ItemType directory -WhatIf`

Comment: Nice, thanks.  Could you explain why the braces {  } are needed around the $_?

Comment: It's part of the PowerShell syntax, to refer to the pipelined object to a parameter that accepts pipeline input. ForEach-Object and Where-Object, for instance, also requires curly braces (but both got additional new syntax since v3)

Answer (score 2):

[`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2) accepts the parameter `-Path` to be piped and it can be an array of strings.

Then, you can create an object with a property `Path` that contains all the needed folders to be created

```
<#
 # a simple array as example,
 # but it could be the result of any enumerable,
 # such as Get-ChildItem and stuff
 #>
$FoldersToCreate = @('a', 'b', 'c')

# creates the folders a, b and c at the current working directory
[PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $FoldersToCreate } | New-Item -ItemType Directory
```

Or, alternatively :

```
$FoldersToCreate |
    Select-Object @{ name = "Path"; expression = { "c:\testDir\$_" } } |
    New-Item -ItemType Directory
```